# Run a service on a schedule and/or on demand

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

I have a clean up service that needs to be ran on a schedule and sometimes on demand. My first thought was to create a windows service but a windows service cant be ran on demand. So, I am thinking of creating a ASP.NET web api site to run this background process. This way I can run the cleanup service on demand from a webpage and I can have a windows service call the web api url to run the service.

So there will be a Web API site that will execute the cleanup logic and both a webpage and a windows service can call this web api service to cleanup.

Do you see anything wrong with this idea? Is there a better way to do this

Comment: why not do a windows console app instead? you can then schedule it to run whenever, and run it yourself just by opening it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that it needs to be ran remotely.

Comment: Seems like a good idea the way you suggested.

Comment: What type of Remotely? Anywhere over the internet or within a local domain environment?

Comment: This will be in a local domain behind firewall.

Comment: Within the domain, permissions allowing, you can remotely execute a process on a domain machine using WMI or the PSEXEC utility among others.

Comment: You can try to do it without windows service using only ASP.NET. There is a good article about background tasks http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: I'd use Hangfire as pointed out in the article above. You can have recurrent jobs and on demand. You also get a dashboard to manage your jobs and check if they are running correctly.

Comment: I'm not saying this is the best way to go about this, but Windows services *can* be run on demand.  (But on the other hand aren't a good way to do something periodically.  That's what the Task Manager is for.)